# Why does super() not get called in the other constuctor?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, this, super

If both `House()` and `House(name)` are called then why is not "Building" printed two times, but instead one time?

```
class Building {
    Building() {
        System.out.println("Buiding");
    }
    Building(String name) {
        this();
        System.out.println("Building: String Constructor" + name);
    }
}
class House extends Building {
    House() {
        System.out.println("House ");
    }
    House(String name) {
        this();
        System.out.println("House: String Constructor" + name);
    }
}
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new House(" OK");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Buiding
House
House: String Constructor OK
```

Comment: Constructors are chained, so `House(String)` calls `House()` (using `this()`), which calls `Building()` (implicitly, the compiler adds `super()` at the start if there is no explicit call). And that means that `Building` is only printed once.

Comment: So because I provided `this()` in `House(String)` , compiler didn't put any `super()` , but in `House()` there neither of them so compiler put one?

Comment: Correct. You wouldn't want to call `super()` twice for the same object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`House(String name)` calls `this()` which is the same as `House()`.
`House()` implicitly calls `super()` which is the same as `Building()`.

You never call `Building(String name)`.

`House(String name)` could call `super(name)` to do that.

Answer (score 1):

The basic rule of a compiled constructor below is the compiled form of a constructor

1. Call to either a current class constructor `this(args if any)` or to a superclass constructor `super(args if any)`. If it's not present then the compiler will keep this `super()`.
2. Call the instance block.
3. Rest of the code written in the .java file

**Java code**

```
Bean () {
    System.out.println("Inside Bean()");
}
```

**After Compilation**

```
Bean () {
    super(); // added by compiler
    // call to instance block
    System.out.println("Inside Bean()");
}
```

So once you follow this rule then you can understand that from `House(String name)` the call will be going to `House()` because you gave `this()`. From `House()` the first call will be `super()` (because there is no call given manually by you), which will only invoke `Building()` and the same will again call `super()`, which in this case is Object class.